# Normal vector to a line defined y = x tan(alpha)

Tags: calculus, vectors

Solving applied mathematics question, and need the boundary condition for a boundary that is defined $z = x\tan(\alpha)$, which involves finding the normal to this line.

I was thinking if $z= x\tan(\alpha)$ then $\nabla z = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
\tan(\alpha)\\
0\\
0
\end{array}
\right)$

but this, normalised (divide by norm) is just $e_\underline{x}$, which clearly is not orthogonal to this line.

How would I go about finding this normal?

Comment: May have just solved it... so  $F = x\tan(\alpha) - z \equiv 0$, which is a level surface of constant value 0.

Taking $\nabla F$ we get $\underline{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\tan^2(\alpha)+1}} \left(
\begin{array}{c}
\tan(\alpha)\\
0\\
-1
\end{array}
\right)$

which is now the unit normal vector, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the gradient of the function:

$$
f(x,y,z) = z - x\tan(\alpha)
$$

not $\nabla z$.